# Multiple entries for the same bucket(default) in the passwd file

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, fuse, s3fs

I am trying to re-run an Ansible script on an old 3rd party integration, the command looks like this:

```
- name: "mount s3fs Fuse FS on boot from [REDACTED] on [REDACTED]"
  mount:
    name: "{{ [REDACTED] }}/s3/file_access"
    src: "{{ s3_file_access_bucket }}:{{ s3_file_access_key }}"
    fstype: fuse.s3fs
    opts: "_netdev,uid={{ uid }},gid={{ group }},mp_umask=022,allow_other,nonempty,endpoint={{ s3_file_access_region }}"
    state: mounted
  tags:
    - [REDACTED]
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
fatal: [REDACTED]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error mounting /home/[REDACTED]: s3fs: there are multiple entries for the same bucket(default) in the passwd file.\n"}
```

I'm trying to find a passwd file to clean out, but I don't know where to find one.

Anyone recognizes this error?

Comment: That error comes straight from s3fs, so perhaps some of the documentation for configuring s3fs would point you at the write place. There is a discussion of credentials files [here](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse#examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s3fs checks `/etc/passwd-s3fs` and `$HOME/.passwd-s3fs` for credentials.  It appears that one of these files has duplicate entries that you need to remove.

Your Ansible `src` stanza also attempts to supply credentials but I do not believe this will work.  Instead you can supply these via the `AWSACCESSKEYID` and `AWSSECRETACCESSKEY` environment variables.